# R: ggplot with 6 different groups: Have 5 solid lines and for one group a dashed line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data:

```
structure(list(Date = c("01.08.2018", "02.08.2018", "03.08.2018", 
"04.08.2018", "01.09.2018", "02.09.2018", "03.09.2018", "04.09.2018", 
"01.08.2018", "02.08.2018", "03.08.2018", "04.08.2018", "01.09.2018", 
"02.09.2018", "03.09.2018", "04.09.2018", "01.08.2018", "02.08.2018", 
"03.08.2018", "04.08.2018", "01.09.2018", "02.09.2018", "03.09.2018", 
"04.09.2018"), Return = c(0.1, 0.4, 0.6, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 
0.5, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, -0.3, 1, -0.4, 0.4, 0.3, -0.3, 
0.2, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6), Rating = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

I would like to use ggplot to have a plot with the Return on the y-axis and the Date on the x-axis. The lines in the plot should be from the 6 different Ratings (1,2,3,4,5 and NA). How can I change the line from the NA Rating to a dashed line and keep the other lines from the Ratings 1 to 5 solid?

I have tried the following:

```
ggplot(Data, aes(x=`Date`, y=`Return`, group=`Rating`, fill=`Rating`, color=`Rating`)) + 
  geom_line(size=1) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette="Paired")
```

My main problem is how to get the dashed line for the group with Rating NA. What do I need to add to the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `Rating` in the `linetype` in your `aes`, to then use `scale_linetype_manual` to set Na to dashed:

```
Data <- Data %>%
  mutate(Rating = fifelse(is.na(Rating),"NA",as.character(Rating)))

ggplot(Data, aes(x= Date, y= Return,group = Rating, color= Rating,linetype = Rating)) + 
  geom_line(size=1) +
  scale_linetype_manual(breaks = c("NA",1:5),values = c("dashed",rep("solid",5)))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! When I run it with my original data, the x-axis with date does not start on 01.08.2018, how can I specify that 01.08.2018 is written on the x-xis?

Comment: There is a `scale_x_date` for the dates, and you can force the date you want in the `breaks` of such function